# Can't figure out what is wrong with my conditional

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements

This is a web scraper code I'm running to port all my university modules into csv file and I am not able to understand why my if/else statement won't work, tried many different solutions but still no luck. Maybe I'm missing something?
Here's the code (conditional is at the bottom):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, BeautifulStoneSoup
# import requests
import csv

with open('timetable.html', encoding='UTF-8', newline='') as html_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')

csv_file = open('lol.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['Subject', 'Start date', 'Start time', 'End time', 'Location'])

table = soup.find('table')

for modulis in table.find_all('td', class_='modclass'):
    # randam modulį

    # randam modulio pavadinimą

    pav = modulis.find_all('a')[1]
    name = pav['title']
    print(name)

    # modulio laiko pradžia

    time1 = modulis.text[0:5]
    print(time1)

    # modulio laiko pabaiga

    time2 = modulis.text[6:11]
    print(time2)

    # modulio vieta

    aud = modulis.find('a').text[1:]
    print(aud)

    # modulio data

    data = modulis.parent.find('td', class_='date').text
    if data[0] == 0:
        rand = '2019.' + data
    else:
        rand = '2018.' + data
    # rašom csv
    print(rand)
    csv_writer.writerow([name, rand, time1, time2, aud])
```

It never evaluates as true, so it always goes into else statement ant puts the wrong year in.
All my dates end up 2018.xx.xx, but these months which start with 0 should start with 2019.xx.xx

Also, data is ALWAYS in the format xx.xx, so data[0] always picks up the first number.

Comment: You probably meant `if data[0] == '0':`, as `data` is text.

Comment: Best solution is to put a `breakpoint` there and check it out...

Comment: That's it! all these hours for nothing, I knew that it would be such a silly mistake in the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `data` as text, then evaluate it as an int. Just change it to '0' and it should work.

```
...
data = modulis.parent.find('td', class_='date').text
if data[0] == '0':
    rand = '2019.' + data
else:
    rand = '2018.' + data
...
```

Comment: For not duplicating, can write: `prefix = 2019 if data[0] == '0' else 2018 and then: `rand = f'{prefix}.{data}'